# Able to ping two machines however unable to after running a script

Tags: bash, fedora, iptables, routing, firewall

I've been trying to fix this for the past few days however I've had no success. This is not my script, it's someone else's I found on GITHUB with some slight modifications I made ( https://github.com/ianlee/standalone-fw ). My script wasn't working so I thought I might try someone else's to see if there's would work but it isn't and I don't want the solution to mines however I'm completely stuck so here I am. These are all bash scripts.

My current setup is 2 virtual machines, both running Fedora's latest version. Both of them have a NAT Network as well as Internal Network so that they're able to communicate with each other. When I made the NAT Network, I gave it the Network CIDR of 192.168.10.0/24. Enp0s1 is the NAT Network connection and Enp0s8 is the Internal Network.

I run the following 2 scripts so that I can ping each other, the 'internal' machine

```
EXTERNAL_INTERFACE="enp0s1"
INTERNAL_GATEWAY_BINDING="1"
INTERNAL_INTERFACE="enp0s8"
INTERNAL_SUBNET="192.168.10"
INTERNAL_BINDING="2"

DNS_IP1="8.8.8.8"
DNS_IP2="8.8.4.4"

ifconfig $EXTERNAL_INTERFACE down 
ifconfig $INTERNAL_INTERFACE $INTERNAL_SUBNET.$INTERNAL_BINDING up 
route add default gw $INTERNAL_SUBNET.$INTERNAL_GATEWAY_BINDING

echo -e "$DNS_IP1\nnameserver $DNS_IP2\n" >/etc/resolv.conf
```

And this on the external machine, the one that is going to be running the script,

```
FIREWALL_IP="192.168.10.5"
EXTERNAL_SUBNET="192.168.0.0"
INTERNAL_INTERFACE="enp0s8"
INTERNAL_SUBNET="192.168.10"
INTERNAL_BINDING="1"
DNS_IP1="8.8.8.8"
DNS_IP2="8.8.4.4"

ifconfig $INTERNAL_INTERFACE $INTERNAL_SUBNET.$INTERNAL_BINDING up

route add -net $INTERNAL_SUBNET.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 gw $INTERNAL_SUBNET.$INTERNAL_BINDING

echo "1" >/proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward

route add -net $EXTERNAL_SUBNET netmask 255.255.255.0 gw $FIREWALL_IP
echo -e "$DNS_IP1\nnameserver $DNS_IP2\n" >/etc/resolv.conf
```

Where 192.168.10.5 is the address with internet connectivity on Enp0s1. I'm able to ping from 192.168.10.1 and 192.168.10.2 between each other just fine, however then I try running the script,

```
#interface name
EXTERNAL="enp0s1"
INTERNAL="enp0s8"
INTERNAL_NETWORK="192.168.10.0/24"

#Allowing ports
TCP_ALLOW_PORTS_IN="22,80,443,8080,3131" #from these ports (acting as a client)
TCP_ALLOW_PORTS_OUT="22,80,443,8080,3131"
UDP_ALLOW_PORTS_IN="80"
UDP_ALLOW_PORTS_OUT="80"

#internal server ip
INTERNAL_SERVER_IP="192.168.10.2"
TCP_ALLOW_PORTS_IN_SERVER="80,22,443,8080,3131" #acting as server (allow connections to these ports)
TCP_ALLOW_PORTS_OUT_SERVER="80,22,443,8080,3131"
UDP_ALLOW_PORTS_IN_SERVER="80"
UDP_ALLOW_PORTS_OUT_SERVER="80"
ICMP_ALLOW_TYPES="0,8"


#block traffic to and from these IP addresses
IP_BLOCK=""

#block these ports regardless of IP or protocol.  
BLOCK_PORTS_IN="0,23"
BLOCK_PORTS_OUT="0,23"

MAXIMIZE_THROUGHPUT="20"
MINIMIZE_DELAY="21,22"

DNS_PORT_IN="53"
DNS_PORT_OUT="53"
DHCP_PORT_IN="67"
DHCP_PORT_OUT="68"

#empty all existing chains
iptables -t filter -F
iptables -t mangle -F
iptables -t nat -F

#set policies to drop
iptables -P OUTPUT DROP
iptables -P FORWARD DROP
iptables -P INPUT DROP

#SNAT
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o $EXTERNAL -j MASQUERADE
#DNAT
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i $EXTERNAL -p tcp -m multiport --dports $TCP_ALLOW_PORTS_IN_SERVER -j DNAT --to $INTERNAL_SERVER_IP
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i $EXTERNAL -p udp -m multiport --dports $UDP_ALLOW_PORTS_IN_SERVER -j DNAT --to $INTERNAL_SERVER_IP

arr=$(echo $ICMP_ALLOW_TYPES | tr "," "\n")
for x in $arr
do
    iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i $EXTERNAL -p icmp --icmp-type $x -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j DNAT --to $INTERNAL_SERVER_IP
done
#MANGLE
iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -p tcp -m multiport --sports $MINIMIZE_DELAY -j TOS --set-tos Minimize-Delay
iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -p tcp -m multiport --sports $MAXIMIZE_THROUGHPUT -j TOS --set-tos Maximize-Throughput
iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -p tcp -m multiport --dports $MINIMIZE_DELAY -j TOS --set-tos Minimize-Delay
iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -p tcp -m multiport --dports $MAXIMIZE_THROUGHPUT -j TOS --set-tos Maximize-Throughput


iptables -N dhcpin
iptables -N dhcpout
iptables -N dhcpforward
iptables -N blockin
iptables -N blockout
iptables -N necessitiesin
iptables -N necessitiesout
iptables -N necessitiesforward
iptables -N icmpin
iptables -N udpin
iptables -N tcpin
iptables -N udpout
iptables -N tcpout


#chain for blocking Inbound traffic
#block inbound traffic from specific IPs 
if [[ -n $IP_BLOCK ]]; then
    iptables -A blockin -i $EXTERNAL  -s $IP_BLOCK -j DROP
fi
#block inbound traffic from a source address from the outside matching your internal network.
iptables -A blockin -i $EXTERNAL  -s $INTERNAL_NETWORK -j DROP

#block syn and fin bits.
iptables -A blockin -i $EXTERNAL  -p tcp ! --syn -m state --state NEW -j DROP
iptables -A blockin -i $EXTERNAL  -p tcp --tcp-flags SYN,FIN SYN,FIN -j DROP
iptables -A blockout  -i $INTERNAL -p tcp ! --syn -m state --state NEW -j DROP
iptables -A blockout  -i $INTERNAL -p tcp --tcp-flags SYN,FIN SYN,FIN  -j DROP

#block inbound traffic to and from specified ports
iptables -A blockin -i $EXTERNAL  -p udp -m multiport --sports $BLOCK_PORTS_IN -j DROP
iptables -A blockin -i $EXTERNAL  -p udp -m multiport --dports $BLOCK_PORTS_IN -j DROP
iptables -A blockin -i $EXTERNAL  -p tcp -m multiport --sports $BLOCK_PORTS_IN -j DROP
iptables -A blockin -i $EXTERNAL  -p tcp -m multiport --dports $BLOCK_PORTS_IN -j DROP

#drop SYN packets from ports less than 1024
iptables -A blockin -i $EXTERNAL  -p tcp -m multiport --sports 0:1023 -m state --state NEW -j DROP
iptables -A blockin -i $EXTERNAL  -p udp -m multiport --sports 0:1023 -m state --state NEW -j DROP

#drop SYN packets to high ports
iptables -A blockin -i $EXTERNAL  -p tcp -m multiport --dports 32768:32775,137:139,111,515 -j DROP
iptables -A blockin -i $EXTERNAL  -p udp -m multiport --dports 32768:32775,137:139 -j DROP

#block outbound traffic from specific IPs
if [[ -n $IP_BLOCK ]]; then
    iptables -A blockout  -i $INTERNAL -d $IP_BLOCK -j DROP
fi
iptables -A blockout  -i $INTERNAL ! -s $INTERNAL_NETWORK -j DROP

#block out bound to and from specified ports
iptables -A blockout  -i $INTERNAL -p udp -m multiport --sports $BLOCK_PORTS_OUT -j DROP
iptables -A blockout  -i $INTERNAL -p udp -m multiport --dports $BLOCK_PORTS_OUT -j DROP
iptables -A blockout  -i $INTERNAL -p tcp -m multiport --sports $BLOCK_PORTS_OUT -j DROP
iptables -A blockout  -i $INTERNAL -p tcp -m multiport --dports $BLOCK_PORTS_OUT -j DROP

#drop SYN packets from ports less than 1024
iptables -A blockout  -i $INTERNAL -p tcp -m multiport --sports 0:1023 -m state --state NEW -j DROP
iptables -A blockout  -i $INTERNAL -p udp -m multiport --sports 0:1023 -m state --state NEW -j DROP

#Block all external traffic directed to ports 32768 – 32775, 137 – 139, TCP ports 111 and 515. 
iptables -A blockout  -i $INTERNAL -p tcp -m multiport --dports 32768:32775,137:139,111,515 -j DROP
iptables -A blockout  -i $INTERNAL -p udp -m multiport --dports 32768:32775,137:139 -j DROP

#allow inbound udp dns traffic
iptables -A necessitiesin -i $EXTERNAL -p udp -m multiport --sports $DNS_PORT_IN -j ACCEPT
iptables -A necessitiesforward -i $EXTERNAL -o $INTERNAL -p udp -m multiport --sports $DNS_PORT_IN -j ACCEPT

#allow inbound tcp dns  traffic
iptables -A necessitiesin -i $EXTERNAL -p tcp -m multiport --sports $DNS_PORT_IN -j ACCEPT
iptables -A necessitiesforward -i $EXTERNAL -o $INTERNAL -p tcp -m multiport --sports $DNS_PORT_IN -j ACCEPT

#allow outbound udp dns traffic
iptables -A necessitiesout -o $EXTERNAL -p udp -m multiport --dports $DNS_PORT_OUT -j ACCEPT
iptables -A necessitiesforward -o $EXTERNAL -i $INTERNAL -p udp -m multiport --dports $DNS_PORT_OUT -j ACCEPT

#allow outbound tcp dns  traffic
iptables -A necessitiesout -o $EXTERNAL -p tcp -m multiport --dports $DNS_PORT_OUT -j ACCEPT
iptables -A necessitiesforward -o $EXTERNAL -i $INTERNAL -p tcp -m multiport --dports $DNS_PORT_OUT -j ACCEPT

#allow inbound udp dhcp traffic
iptables -A dhcpin -i $EXTERNAL -p udp  --dport $DHCP_PORT_OUT  -m multiport --sports $DHCP_PORT_IN  -j ACCEPT
iptables -A dhcpforward -i $EXTERNAL -o $INTERNAL -p udp  --dport $DHCP_PORT_OUT -m multiport --sports $DHCP_PORT_IN   -j ACCEPT

#allow inbound tcp dhcp traffic
iptables -A dhcpin -i $EXTERNAL -p tcp --dport $DHCP_PORT_OUT  -m multiport --sports $DHCP_PORT_IN  -j ACCEPT
iptables -A dhcpforward -i $EXTERNAL -o $INTERNAL -p tcp --dport $DHCP_PORT_OUT  -m multiport --sports $DHCP_PORT_IN   -j ACCEPT

#allow outbound udp dhcp traffic
iptables -A dhcpout -o $EXTERNAL -p udp  --sport $DHCP_PORT_IN -m multiport --dports $DHCP_PORT_OUT  -j ACCEPT
iptables -A dhcpforward -o $EXTERNAL -i $INTERNAL -p udp  --sport $DHCP_PORT_IN -m multiport --dports $DHCP_PORT_OUT   -j ACCEPT

#allow outbound tcp dhcp traffic
iptables -A dhcpout -o $EXTERNAL -p tcp --sport $DHCP_PORT_IN  -m multiport --dports $DHCP_PORT_OUT  -j ACCEPT
iptables -A dhcpforward -o $EXTERNAL -i $INTERNAL -p tcp  --sport $DHCP_PORT_IN -m multiport --dports $DHCP_PORT_OUT -j ACCEPT

#ICMP Chain
arr=$(echo $ICMP_ALLOW_TYPES | tr "," "\n")
for x in $arr
do
  iptables -A icmpin -i $EXTERNAL -p icmp --icmp-type $x -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
done

#allow inbound udp user defined traffic
iptables -A udpin -i $EXTERNAL -o $INTERNAL -p udp -m multiport --sports $UDP_ALLOW_PORTS_IN -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT # acting as a client
iptables -A udpin -i $EXTERNAL -o $INTERNAL -p udp -m multiport --dports $UDP_ALLOW_PORTS_IN_SERVER -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT # acting as a server
#add inbound udp chain to default input chain

#allow inbound user defined traffic
iptables -A tcpin -i $EXTERNAL -o $INTERNAL -p tcp -m multiport --sports $TCP_ALLOW_PORTS_IN -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT # acting as a client
iptables -A tcpin -i $EXTERNAL -o $INTERNAL -p tcp -m multiport --dports $TCP_ALLOW_PORTS_IN_SERVER -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT # acting as a server

#allow outbound udp user defined traffic
iptables -A udpout -o $EXTERNAL -i $INTERNAL -p udp -m multiport --dports $UDP_ALLOW_PORTS_OUT -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT # acting as a client
iptables -A udpout -o $EXTERNAL -i $INTERNAL -p udp -m multiport --sports $UDP_ALLOW_PORTS_OUT_SERVER -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT # acting as a server

#allow outbound tcp user defined traffic
iptables -A tcpout -o $EXTERNAL -i $INTERNAL -p tcp -m multiport --dports $TCP_ALLOW_PORTS_OUT -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT # acting as a client
iptables -A tcpout -o $EXTERNAL -i $INTERNAL -p tcp -m multiport --sports $TCP_ALLOW_PORTS_OUT_SERVER -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT # acting as a server


iptables -A INPUT -j dhcpin
iptables -A OUTPUT -j dhcpout
iptables -A FORWARD -j dhcpforward

iptables -A FORWARD -j blockin
iptables -A INPUT -j blockin
iptables -A FORWARD -j blockout
iptables -A INPUT -j blockout

iptables -A INPUT -j necessitiesin
iptables -A OUTPUT -j necessitiesout
iptables -A FORWARD -j necessitiesforward

iptables -A FORWARD -p icmp -j icmpin
iptables -A FORWARD -p udp -j udpin
iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp -j tcpin
iptables -A FORWARD -p udp -j udpout
iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp -j tcpout
```

I run that on the external machine and I get no response when I try pinging for any of the allowed ports for TCP or UDP. I can see it go through via Wireshark but the ping command itself doesn't yield any response. Any help would be appreciated as this is really racking my brain.

Answer (score 2):

So your external network address(fw cpu) is 192.168.0.0/24 is facing your gateway which leaves 192.168.0.1 - 192.168.0.254 as viable host addresses your devices connected to it, but your hosts are on 192.168.10.0/24 which is a different network address than 192.168.0. You would need to add a router in there in order to allow 2 different network addresses to communicate otherwise the traffic the fw will not route to the 192.168.10.0/24. Are you using virtual box?

Comment: Ah I completely missed that, and yes I am using Virtual Box with NAT Network and Internal. Sorry I'm completely new to Linux, just started learning a month or so ago. So would I change the hosts to 192.168.0.0/24? When I made the NAT Network, I gave it a CIDR of 192.168.10.0/24 so would changing it to 192.168.0.0/24 fix it?

Comment: LOL Also did you read the file in the git describing the assignment? One of the requirements is controlling ICMP traffic. Ping is an  ICMP function.

Comment: In vbox NAT only allows guest>external network access, if you need access in all directions use bridged network so the guest systems will receive direct access to the network, to which the host system has been connected. http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html#network_bridged

Comment: Yep I did lol, I used hping3, miswrote and didn't realize I wrote ping instead until your comment. I did what you suggested with a bridged connection but I still have the same issue with the network address being 192.168.10.0 and 192.168.0.0